# Conditional row numbering within groups

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

**My table looks like the following:**

| ID | Dummy | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | 01.01.2021 |
| 3 | 1 | 01.02.2021 |
| 3 | 1 | 01.03.2021 |
| 3 | 0 | 01.04.2021 |
| 3 | 1 | 01.05.2021 |
| 3 | 0 | 01.06.2021 |
| 3 | 0 | 01.07.2021 |
| 3 | 0 | 01.08.2021 |
| 3 | 1 | 01.09.2021 |
| 3 | 1 | 01.10.2021 |
| 4 | 0 | 01.01.2021 |
| 4 | 0 | 01.02.2021 |
| 4 | 0 | 01.03.2021 |
| 4 | 1 | 01.04.2021 |
| 4 | 1 | 01.05.2021 |
| 4 | 0 | 01.06.2021 |
| 4 | 1 | 01.07.2021 |
| 4 | 0 | 01.08.2021 |
| 4 | 1 | 01.09.2021 |
| 4 | 1 | 01.10.2021 |

Firstly, **within each ID group**, I want to determine sequences of ones from Dummy column. **The sequences can only tolerate 2 or fewer consecutive zeros.** One way of doing it is to create 2 lags, 2 leads, summing up 5 dummies (while using `COALESCE` for lags and leads) and filtering by a condition that the sum of all 5 should be greater than or equal to 3.

The second step is where I actually got stuck.

I want to number those groups while incrementing them by 1 each time and state the associated min & max dates. The desired output should look like the table below.

**Desire output:**

| ID | Group | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | 01.01.2021 | 01.05.2021 |
| 3 | 2 | 01.09.2021 | 01.10.2021 |
| 4 | 1 | 01.04.2021 | 01.05.2021 |
| 4 | 2 | 01.07.2021 | 01.07.2021 |
| 4 | 3 | 01.09.2021 | 01.10.2021 |

Comment: what version of oracle are you using?

Comment: @Boneist It should be 12g

Comment: This is really screaming "`MATCH_RECOGNIZE`!" at me, but for the life of me, I can't think how to express the pattern of "1 followed by any number of 1s or up to two consecutive 0s". That's why I asked what version, as it's only available from 12c.

Comment: @Boneist you are most probably right. I restated the question and the given answer is the same as yours. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69205564/grouping-binary-variable-by-id-and-min-max-dates

Answer (score 1):

This answers the original version of the question.

Hmmm . . . I'm thinking.  Count up the zero and then put the rows into groups based on the number divided by 2.

```
select id, min(date), max(date),
       row_number() over (partition by id order by min(date)) as grouping
from (select t.*,
             sum(dummy - 1) over (partition by id order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where dummy = 1
group by id, ceil(seqnum / 2);
```

Comment: I have noticed that I miss-stated a critical part. I said that "the sequences can only tolerate 2 or fewer zeros. ", however, it should be 2 or fewer consecutive zeros.

Comment: @Larx . . . Perhaps you should ask a *new* question, with appropriate sample data and desired results.

Comment: the sample and desired results are consistent with what I actually wanted to do. The problem was the wording of the question, which I edited.