# Grouping Binary Variable By ID and Min/Max Dates

Tags: sql, oracle

| Date | Emp ID | Dummy |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2021 | 5 | 1 |
| 01.02.2021 | 5 | 1 |
| 01.03.2021 | 5 | 1 |
| 01.04.2021 | 5 | 1 |
| 01.05.2021 | 5 | 0 |
| 01.06.2021 | 5 | 1 |
| 01.07.2021 | 5 | 1 |
| 01.01.2021 | 8 | 1 |
| 01.02.2021 | 8 | 1 |
| 01.03.2021 | 8 | 1 |
| 01.04.2021 | 8 | 0 |
| 01.05.2021 | 8 | 0 |
| 01.06.2021 | 8 | 0 |
| 01.07.2021 | 8 | 1 |

Basically, I want to group the data by uninterrupted sequences of ones from the dummy column for each employee and state the associated max/min dates.

The desired output should look like this:

| Emp ID | Min Date | Max Date | Group Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 01.01.2021 | 01.04.2021 | 1 |
| 5 | 01.06.2021 | 01.07.2021 | 2 |
| 8 | 01.01.2021 | 01.03.2021 | 1 |
| 8 | 01.07.2021 | 01.07.2021 | 2 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Oracle 12, this is the type of problem that `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` is intended to solve:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  PARTITION BY Emp_ID
  ORDER     BY dt
  MEASURES
    FIRST(dt) AS min_date,
    LAST(dt)  AS max_date,
    MATCH_NUMBER() AS group_number
  PATTERN (one+)
  DEFINE
    one AS dummy = 1
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( dt, Emp_ID, Dummy ) AS
SELECT DATE '2021-01-01', 5, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-01-02', 5, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-01-03', 5, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-01-04', 5, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-01-05', 5, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-01-06', 5, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-01-07', 5, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-01-01', 8, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-01-02', 8, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-01-03', 8, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-01-04', 8, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-01-05', 8, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-01-06', 8, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-01-07', 8, 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | EMP_ID | MIN_DATE | MAX_DATE | GROUP_NUMBER |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 5 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 2021-01-04 00:00:00 | 1 |
> | 5 | 2021-01-06 00:00:00 | 2021-01-07 00:00:00 | 2 |
> | 8 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 2021-01-03 00:00:00 | 1 |
> | 8 | 2021-01-07 00:00:00 | 2021-01-07 00:00:00 | 2 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b229e6f25b3e3ee501dc70f2c4255f82)*

Comment: I am received an error of ambiguously defined column. The equivalent of the table called "table_name" in my query is a CTE. Can it be related to that?

Comment: @Larx You need to check for two columns with the same name. I do not have access to your query so that is something you will have debug yourself.

Comment: I defined 2x min_date... Fixed it and it works beautifully now. Much obliged, thank you.